# check type in multiple upload in php

Tags: php, file, loops

I just want to upload multiple files in PHP and I want to if one of the files types isn't SRT just cancel the whole loop and get one error, but when I'm doing that the error will be repeated based on the counting of files and result is like this:

> ERROR 
>   ERROR 
>   ERROR

I want to if one of the conditions wasn't ok, just cancel the operation and show the error without repeating

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['upload_multiple']) && !empty($_FILES['files']['name'][0])) {

    $files = $_FILES['files'];
    $allowed = ['srt', 'idx', 'sub'];
    $msg = [];

    foreach ($files['name'] as $position => $file_name) {
        $files_name = $files['name'][$position];
        $files_tmp_name = $files['tmp_name'][$position];
        $files_type = explode('.', $files_name);
        $files_type = end($files_type);

        if (in_array($files_type, $allowed)) {
            move_uploaded_file($files_tmp_name, 'upload/' . $files_name);
        }else {
            $msg[] = 'ERROR <BR>';
        }
    }

} else {
    echo "Choose a File!";
}

?>
```

Comment: echo the move_uploaded_file call, what number does it come back with?

Comment: @farkie I want to check the files after that if conditions was ok, just began the uploading

Comment: What is the question? Please edit to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <?php

    if (isset($_POST['upload_multiple']) && !empty($_FILES['files']['name'][0])) {

        $files = $_FILES['files'];
        $allowed = ['srt', 'idx', 'sub'];
        $msg = [];

        array_walk($files, function($file) use (&$msg){
            $path_extension = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            if (!in_array($path_extension, $allowed)) {
               $msg[0] = 'ERROR <BR>';
            }
        }

        if(empty($msg)){

        foreach ($files['name'] as $position => $file_name) {
            $files_name = $files['name'][$position];
            $files_tmp_name = $files['tmp_name'][$position];
            $files_type = explode('.', $files_name);
            $files_type = end($files_type);
            move_uploaded_file($files_tmp_name, 'upload/' . $files_name);
        }
        }

    } else {
        echo "Choose a File!";
    }

?>
```

Comment: It's better to check filenames before saving ANY files. This code will save and not delete files which was saved before file with invalid extension.

Comment: well, than i can recommend array_walk function

Comment: @Anton I want to file don't be saved and get the error

Comment: there you go, i modified the previous post

Comment: i dont know if you have to use $files['name'] instead of $files, i don't see the structure of array

Comment: @buzlee TNX I think your solution can solve my problem, if I had an another problem can I contact you?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php

if (isset($_POST['upload_multiple']) && !empty($_FILES['files']['name'][0])) {

    $files = $_FILES['files'];
    $allowed = ['srt', 'idx', 'sub'];
    $msg = [];

    $extensionsAreValid = true;
    foreach ($files['name'] as $position => $file_name) {
        $files_name = $files['name'][$position];
        $files_type = end(explode('.', $files_name));

        if (!in_array($files_type, $allowed)) {
            $msg[] = "ERROR: $files_name has invalid extension. <BR>";
            $extensionsAreValid = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ($extensionsAreValid) {
       foreach ($files['name'] as $position => $file_name) {
           move_uploaded_file($files['tmp_name'][$position], 'upload/' . $files['name'][$position]);
       }
    }
} else {
    echo "Choose a File!";
}
```